# Error in uploading file to server java.lang.nullpointerexception connection is null exception

Tags: java, database, server, ftp-server

I am working on a `java` application. I recieve exception when I send a file to server. The error is: `Error in connection =java.lang.NullPointerException`

The code is below:

```
 File file = new File(localFileFullName);
        if (!(file.isDirectory())) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                FileInputStream input = null;
                FileInputStream input1 = null;
                try {
                    input = new FileInputStream(new File(localFileFullName));
                    if (input != null) {

                        hostDir = hostDir.replaceAll("//", "/");
                       logger.info("uploading host dir : " + hostDir);


                       //new 
                       FTPClient ftpClient= DBConnection.connect();  
                       String secondRemoteFile = hostDir;
                       logger.error("connect to the server"+ftpClient.isConnected());

                       System.out.println("Start uploading second file");
                       OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);
                       byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
                       int read = 0;

                       while ((read = input.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                           outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
                       }
                       input.close();
                       outputStream.close();

                       boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
                       if (completed) {
                           System.out.println("The second file is uploaded successfully.");
                       }
     ftpClient.disconnect();
 } else {
                         logger.error("uploading file input null.");
             }

                }catch(CopyStreamException cs)
                {
                    logger.error("Copy StreamExeption is come "+cs);

                } catch(Exception ex)
                {
                     logger.error("Error in connection ="+ex);



                }finally {
//                  boolean disconnect= DBConnection.disConnect();
                    input.close();

//                  logger.info("Connection close from DBConnection"+disconnect);
                }

            } else {
                  logger.info("uploading file is not exists.");
            }
        }
```

And then the other exception is come socket write error.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not de-escape the hostDir string.

If you leave out that line the code should work.

The other possible error is that your connection does fail, 
to check that we need more information about the exception

Comment: if i am secape the step the dont work because this is the server file path where the file is store                                                                         Software caused connection abort: socket write error                         Software caused connection abort: recv failed                                                              and i have do some change in to my code so now they will show the java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error